# Show column value only once

Tags: oracle

I have data like this:

[image]

And I want to show like this

[image]

All employees have the same position As Manager but I want to show once.

Comment: you can do that in excel but not by selecting the data

Comment: What your wanting to do is generally a function of the presentation layer; not generally a function of the database layer  7 Layers of the OSI Model and this concept mixes two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, but you should do it only for display purposes:

```
WITH a (ename, position, deptno) AS (SELECT 'KING', 'Manager', 10 FROM dual 
                                     UNION ALL 
                                     SELECT 'BLAKE', 'Manager', 30 FROM dual 
                                     UNION ALL 
                                     SELECT 'CLARK', 'Manager', 10 FROM dual 
                                     UNION ALL 
                                     SELECT 'ALLEN', 'Manager', 30 FROM dual 
                                     UNION ALL 
                                     SELECT 'WARD', 'Manager', 30 FROM dual)
SELECT ENAME
     , CASE WHEN position = MAX(position) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM 
                                                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 1 preceding) 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE position 
       END position
     , deptno 
  FROM a
```

That will display `NULL` for the column `POSITION` if the value is the same as in the previous row.